# Inject extra things into default get'ters and set'ters for properties

Tags: c#

Normally you can do something like this for properties:

```
public String s {get; set; }
```

to make a property with default getters and setters.

Additionally, you can implement both of them yourself.

But can I only 'implemement' one of them, say the setter, to do extra things ?

Say something like

```
public String s {
  get;
  set { 
    // some extra code here to happen on any setting of this property
  }

}
```

It appears I can't do this (doesn't compile) and have to introduce a helper private variable, and fill out appropriately the get/set code. Any ideas?

Thanks!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Programmatically insert a method call on each property of a class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7569223/programmatically-insert-a-method-call-on-each-property-of-a-class)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, you can't - automatically implemented properties are "all or nothing"; they can *only* ever implement completely trivial properties. You'll need to introduce a field yourself.

(Personally I don't mind that too much, but I'd really like to be able to write read-only automatic properties which can only be set from the constructor.)

Comment: @George: No, that doesn't make it *truly* read-only. It doesn't stop it from being set outside the constructor, and it doesn't make the underlying field read-only, which is what I'd want.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, compiler won't allow what you're trying to do.  You can setup an auto property like so...

```
public String s { get; private set;}
```

Then have a special set method...

```
public void SetS(string s)
{
     ...logic
}
```

Comment: I failed to mention...this forces consumers to use the SetS method, since the setter has been marked private.